# Evaluate limit of recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Was reading this http://mathonline.wikidot.com/evaluating-limits-of-recursive-sequences and going through these example

sequence 1

$h_{n+1}=\sqrt{(h_n)^2-0.1h_n}$

Sequence 2

$h_{n+1}=\sqrt{(h_n)^2-0.1(h_n)^3}$

and assume $h_1=2$ for both sequence

I assume both sequence limit exist and denote it as L so $L=h_n=h_{n+1}$ getting both $0$, sequence 2 does converge to 0 but sequence 1 gave me a "math error" after pressing the calculator several times as h became a negative value(does this indicate limit 0 is not true)? If so what approach do we use to proof/disproof the limit exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sequence is ill defined. This is because $h_{38}\approx 0.065356853 < 0.1$, which means that

$$h_{38}^2 - 0.1 h_{38} =h_{38}\cdot h_{38}-0.1\cdot h_{38} < 0.1\cdot h_{38} - 0.1 \cdot h_{38} = 0.$$

This means that $h_{39} = \sqrt{h_{38}^2 - 0.1\cdot h_{38}}$ is a square root of a negative number, which is an undefined value.

Therefore we cannot speak of a limit of $h_n$  in the first case, because $h_n$ is not an infinite sequence.